# New ticket is being created when loading a new form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my first question on here, so I am hoping I have not asked it incorrectly.

I have a generic new action on my tickets controller. Whenever I load tickets/new, it is creating a new item in the DB and committing it.

Here is the output from the server when the page is loading.

```
Started GET "/tickets/new" for ::1 at 2016-02-10 21:14:47 -0800
Processing by TicketsController#new as HTML
  Customer Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `customers`.* FROM `customers` WHERE `customers`.`email` = 'tim@tim.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO `tickets` (`category`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (3, '2016-02-11 05:14:47', '2016-02-11 05:14:47')
   (6.4ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered tickets/_new_form.html.erb (23.3ms)
  Rendered tickets/new.html.erb within layouts/application (48.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_user_nav.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_flashes.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_minimal.html.erb (759.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 893ms (Views: 822.1ms | ActiveRecord: 21.3ms)
```

This is the from the tickets controller.

```
def new
    @ticket = Ticket.new
end
```

Here is the code for the form.

```
<%= form_for(@ticket, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.hidden_field(:category) %>
    <%= f.hidden_field(:severity) %>


    <br>
    <%= f.form_group :summary do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :summary, class: 'control-label col-md-2' %>
      <div class='col-md-8'>
        <%= f.text_field :summary, class: 'form-control' %>
        <%= f.error_messages %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.form_group :detail do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :detail, class: 'control-label col-md-2' %>
      <div class='col-md-8'>
        <%= f.text_area :detail, class: 'form-control' %>
        <%= f.error_messages %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <br>


  </div>

  <div class="form-actions col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
    <%= f.submit 'Create', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to "Cancel", tickets_path, class: 'btn' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here are the relevant routes.

```
 resources :tickets do
    collection do
      get :step_1
      get :new_ticket
      get :billing_new_1
      get :internet_step_1
      get :internet_step_2
      get :internet_modem_reset
      get :internet_step_1
      get :internet_step_2
      get :internet_create_1
      get :internet_create_2
      get :tv_step_1
      get :tv_step_2
      get :tv_step_3
      get :tv_create_1
      get :tv_create_2
      get :tv_create_3
      get :closed
      get :sidenav
    end
    member do
      put :close
    end

    resources :notes
    resources :appointments
  end
```

Help!!

--Tim

Comment: could you post your routes please

Comment: your route file... copy past it in your question. NOT AS A COMMENT. Please.

Comment: What happens if you remove `get :new_ticket` ?

Comment: The form and resource routes are irrelevant.  Post the models for customer and ticket.

Comment: Can you post your `Ticketscontroller` please, and also do you have a `Github` repo I could look at?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `tickets` (`category`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (3, '2016-02-11 05:14:47', '2016-02-11 05:14:47')
```

This is getting `category` (`3`) from somewhere, suggesting that there is some functionality *somewhere* which is saving the `@ticket`.

The simplest explanation I can see is that you have a `before_action` somewhere. It would benefit to show your entire `TicketsController`:

```
#app/controllers/tickets_controller.rb
class TicketsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_user #-> something like this??
end
```

---

Since you're new, you can make your routes much more succinct ([multiple resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-multiple-resources-at-the-same-time)):

```
#config/routes.rb
methods = %i(step_1 new_ticket billing_new_1 internet_step_1 internet_step_2 internet_modem_reset internet_create_1 internet_create_2 tv_step_1 tv_step_2 tv_step_3 tv_create_1 tv_create_2 tv_create_3 closed sidenav)

resources :tickets do
  resources :notes, :appointments
  collection do
    methods.each {|method| get method }
  end
  put :close, on: :member
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the input on hte routes. I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up starting the whole ticket class over.
I think the error was in my html.
My guess is that the if statement with the bang was causing the ticket to save, because of an enum with that name on the model.

Here is what I think was the bad html.

```
 <% if @ticket.category == :tv %>
          Ok. Your tv is down, but your internet is still working.
          <br>
          Do you have any more details to add? If so, add them here. If not, just hit sumbit and we will open up a ticket with all of the information that you have provided us.

          <% elsif @ticket.internet! %>
          Ok. Your internet is down, but your tv is still working.
          <br>
          Do you have any more details to add? If so, add them here. If not, just hit sumbit and we will open up a ticket with all of the information that you have provided us.

          <% elsif @ticket.billing %>
          I am fresh out of questions.
          <br>
          Do you have any more details to add? If so, add them here. If not, just hit sumbit and we will open up a ticket with all of the information that you have provided us.
          <% elsif @ticket.category == :internet_and_tv %>
          Ok. Your cable and internet are both down.'%>
          <br>
          Do you have any more details to add? If so, add them here. If not, just hit sumbit and we will open up a ticket with all of the information that you have provided us.'%>
          <% else @ticket.category == :plant %>
          <%end%>
```